# Define a Behave step that works for multiple keywords (e.g. Given, When, and Then)

Tags: python, python-3.x, bdd, python-behave

Is there a way to write a step that works for multiple keywords. Like say my feature is:

```
Scenario: Something happens after navigating 
  Given I navigate to "/"
    And say some cookie gets set
  When I navigate to "/some-other-page"
  Then something happens because of that cookie
```

I'm trying to avoid having to define both:

```
    @given('I navigate to "{uri}"')
    def get(context, uri):
        current_url = BASE_URL + uri
        context.driver.get(current_url)

    @when('I navigate to "{uri}"')
    def get(context, uri):
        current_url = BASE_URL + uri
        context.driver.get(current_url)
```

If you only define one and try to use it as both you get a `raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP:` error. With the above example it's not that bad because the step is simple but it seems like it's bad practice to repeat code and you could have the same thing happening with something more complicated, to me it seems like it would make sense if there was like a @all or @any keyword.

*Apologies if this has been answered somewhere but it's a hard thing to search for as it's hard to find unique search terms for this type of question*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out this can be done using `@step`. e.g.

```
from behave import step

@step('I navigate to "{uri}"')
def step_impl(context, uri):
     current_url = BASE_URL + uri
     context.driver.get(current_url)
```

Will work for:

```
Scenario: Demo how @step can be used for multiple keywords
    Given I navigate to "/"
    When I navigate to "/"
    Then I navigate to "/"
```

Note: Figured this out from the [ticket](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/169) which led to this [file](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/features/step.use_step_library.feature).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use @step, you can also do:

```
@and(u'I navigate to "{uri}"')
 @when(u'I navigate to "{uri}"')
 @given(u'I navigate to "{uri}"')
 def get(context, uri):
     current_url = BASE_URL + uri
     context.driver.get(current_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are conceptual differences between what the @given, @when and @then decorators stand for. You have situations where a step applies to all, some, or only one.

It is all to easy to use @step when the step only applies to 2 situations, and then rely on the test writers to only use the step in the right circumstances. I would encourage people not to do that. Use the following example instead.

```py
@given('step text')
@when('step text')
def step_impl(context):
    pass
```

However when a step is truly applicable to all cases, a good example is a delay step, then use the @step decorator:

```py
@step('delay {duration} second(s)')
def step_impl(context, duration):
    time.sleep(float(duration))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

As a web user
        Given I navigate to "/"and say some cookie gets set
        Then I navigate to "/some-other-page"
        And something happens because of that cookie

Comment: I am doing something like that, but if you don't define the Given and the Then (in your example) as two different functions in your steps file, I get a "raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP:" error. If this is working for you without doing it twice, what does your step definition look like?

Comment: Its working for me. When you write "And" statement following "Then" statement, it considers it as two "Then" statements.

Answer (score -2):

Its working for me. When you write "And" statement following "Then" statement, it considers it as two "Then" statements. Also you should include u' inside given and then statements parenthesis.

Try as below:

```
@given(u'I navigate to "{uri}"')
def get(context, uri):
    current_url = BASE_URL + uri
    context.driver.get(current_url)

@given(u'say some cookie gets set')
def get(context, uri):
    current_url = BASE_URL + uri
    context.driver.get(current_url) 

@then(u'I navigate to "/some-other-page"')
def step_impl(context):
    //your code

@then(u'something happens because of that cookie')
def step_impl(context):
    //your code
```

Comment: Yeah, I say that in my question that it will work if you write both a ```@given('I navigate to "{uri}"')``` and a ```@when('I navigate to "{uri}"')```. You're doing the same thing by defining it twice, just you're doing a ```@given(u'I navigate to "{uri}"')``` and ```@then(u'I navigate to "/some-other-page"')``` which would duplicate the navigation code